# Reset KDE System Monitor (KSysGuard)

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, system-monitoring

Something went wrong while I was attempting to restore a backup, and **KDE System Guard** ceased to display properly.

This is the **correct** display (command running from root: `kdesudo ksysguard`):
[image: [Image of proper display of KSysGuard]]

This is the **incorrect** display (command: `ksysguard`):
[image: [Image of improper display of KSysGuard]]

Here in the incorrect display, the **menu bar is missing**, and the **tab "Process Table" is unclickable**.

I have already tried to remove the directory `~/.kde/share/apps/ksysguard/` but to no avail.

My question: **How do I restore KSysGuard back to factory defaults/normal functionality?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Default Keyboard shortcut to "Enable" or "Disable" (Toggle) the Menu Bar is `Ctrl+M`. I believe that will be the simplest solution.

Comment: Wow!  That's probably what I hit accidentally to make the menu bar disappear in the first place.  I see that KDE now has [a popup to warn that the menu bar will disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x37g2.png).

Answer (score 5):

[globot's answer](https://superuser.com/a/663560/83694) applies to KDE 4, and this question was written for KDE 4, but now that there is KDE Plasma 5, some paths have changed.

**If you are having this issue on KDE Plasma 5, you should remove the line that begins with `MenuBar=` from this file: `~/.config/ksysguardrc`**

Here is a one-liner command that can restore KSysGuard's menu bar in KDE Plasma 5:

```
sed -i '/^MenuBar=/d' ~/.config/ksysguardrc
```

This is the command to run to restore KSysGuard's menu bar in KDE 4:

```
sed -i '/^MenuBar=/d' ~/.kde/share/config/ksysguardrc
```

---

### Explanation

I retroactively determined that [globot's answer](https://superuser.com/a/663560/83694) was correct by finding a backup of the configuration file `~/.kde/share/config/ksysguardrc` that I had made on 26 July 2012 at 19:14 CDT.

Here were the full contents of that file:

```
State=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAAAAAyAAAAIyAAAABAAAAAQAAAAIAAAACPwAAAABAAAAAgAAAAEAAAAWAG0AYQBpAG4AVABvAG8AbABCAGEAcgAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAA

[DownloadDialog Settings]
Height 1080=400
Width 1920=700

[MainWindow]
CommandList=
HostList=
MenuBar=Disabled
SelectedSheets[$e]=ProcessTable.sgrd,SystemLoad2.sgrd
SplitterSizeList=472,325
State=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAAAAAyAAAAJEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAIAAAACPwAAAABAAAAAgAAAAEAAAAWAG0AYQBpAG4AVABvAG8AbABCAGEAcgAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAA
ToolBarsMovable=Disabled
currentSheet=1
isMinimized=false
```

Exactly as expected, `MenuBar` was set to `Disabled`, which disabled the menu bar in KSysGuard in KDE 4.

`~/.kde/share/config/ksysguardrc` isn't used in KDE Plasma 5, so to find the new location of the configuration file, I used `strace`:

```
deltik@workstation [~]# sudo strace -vvvffts1000 ksysguard 2>&1 | grep ksysguardrc
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc",  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 lstat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc",  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 access("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", W_OK) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/etc/xdg/ksysguardrc", 0x7fffe011c4a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 open("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:27 access("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", W_OK) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 open("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc.lock", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_CLOEXEC, 0644) = 14
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 open("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 17
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 stat("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", {st_dev=makedev(252, 1), st_ino=1368016, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=302, st_atime=2015/07/05-23:26:42, st_mtime=2015/07/05-23:26:22, st_ctime=2015/07/05-23:26:22}) = 0
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 open("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC) = 17
[pid  5534] 23:32:30 unlink("/home/deltik/.config/ksysguardrc.lock") = 0
^C
```

The above output shows that `ksysguard` is trying to read configuration from the file `~/.config/ksysguardrc`.

Comment: When started with Ctrl+Escape ksysguard is minimal no menu etc. but when started from menu it's full

Comment: @intika: [Ctrl]+[Escape] by default starts `systemmonitor`, not `ksysguard`.  They are two different programs, titled "System Activity" and "System Monitor" respectively, which can be a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

you can open ~/.kde/share/config/ksysguardrc and set the MenuBar to 'Enabled':
MenuBar=Enabled

if this variable is not present, the menu should be visible by default.

Comment: This is the correct answer for KDE 4.  For KDE Plasma 5, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/936736/83694) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge ksysguard` to remove all installation files; then reinstall with `sudo apt-get install ksysguard`. For example `dpkg -L ksysguard` shows that there's config settings in /usr/share/kde4/config/ksysguard.knsrc too (for me on Kubuntu).

However this error looks a bit more weird to me - it may be that you've somehow managed to make a setting in the window manager that is affecting the display of the ksysguard window - perhaps altered the window type setting?